# Messagebox on file open does not get focus

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that opens a messagebox when the file is opened . However, when I open the file, because of the messagebox, the file and its messagebox do not come to the front of my windows gain focus (they appear on my taskbar and I have to click on it from there). After the messagebox is completed, the file gains focus as normal.

In its simplest form, this code seems to trigger this

```
Sub Auto_Open()
MsgBox ""
End Sub
```

I have tried adding code in to give the window focus before executing the messagebox, but to no success. I don't mind this issue but other people will be using this document. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What version are you running? Can't repro on Excel 2010.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: Does a new workbook with nothing but this code reproduce the problem? See [mcve].

Comment: yes. a new file with nothing but either auto_open or workbook_open results in the same problem.

Comment: I tried my code on a separate computer (also Excel 2013) and had the same results. I removed the message box from auto_open as it wasn't crucial, just preferred. Thank you for your help, though

Answer (score 0):

The legacy `Auto_Open` auto-macro is going to run regardless of the state of `Application.EnableEvents`, which may be a problem if another macro-enabled workbook needs to open that workbook.

I can't reproduce the issue on Excel 2010, with this code in `Module1`:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    MsgBox "Auto_Open()"
End Sub
```

And this code in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Workbook_Open()"
End Sub
```

I get two successive message boxes, first from `Workbook_Open`, then from `Auto_Open`, both show up right where I'd expect them - right in the middle of an empty worksheet:

[image: Workbook_Open() message box right in the middle of an empty worksheet]

[image: Auto_Open() message box, also right in the middle of an empty worksheet]

Try putting the message box in the `Open` event handler of `ThisWorkbook`, see if it helps.